# Why does ssh's “password” prompt take so long to appear?

Tags: ssh

When I try to `ssh`, the password prompt takes too long (almost two minutes) to appear.

Why does this happen?

Comment: The [answer of Gilles](http://askubuntu.com/a/246330/88802) should be *the* answer as explained in the comments, really.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

There are several things that can go wrong. Add `-vvv` to make ssh print a detailed trace of what it's doing, and see where it's pausing.

The problem could be on the client or on the server.

A common problem on the server is if you're connecting from a client for which reverse DNS lookups time out. (A “reverse DNS lookup” means getting back from the client machine's IP address to a host name. It isn't really useful for security, only slightly helpful to diagnose breakin attempts from log entries, but the default configuration does it anyway.) To turn off reverse DNS lookups, add `UseDNS no` to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (you need to be root on the server; remember to restart the SSH service afterwards).

Another thing that [can go wrong](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5621/how-to-speed-my-too-slow-ssh-login) is [GSSAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_Security_Services_Application_Program_Interface) authentication timing out. If you don't know what that is, you're probably not relying on it; you can turn it off by adding the line `GSSAPIAuthentication no` to `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` or `~/.ssh/config` (that's on the client side).

Comment: For me it was the GSSAPIAuthentication problem. Thank you.

Comment: This has been a problem for me when I ssh into a server in my own apartment. Some combination of DynDNS and port fowarding must've made me hit the DNS timeout issue you described. Thank you!

Comment: I also had to disable GSSAPI, it's enabled by default on **Raspberry PI** radpbian.

Comment: +1 for `GSSAPIAuthentication no` ! Vive Gilles !

Comment: Reverse DNS lookup was my problem

Comment: Reverse DNS was the culprit for me as well, and `UseDNS no` fixed it like a charm. I am on an internal network with no DNS server to handle reverse lookups for internal IPs.

Comment: And don't forget to restart the ssh service for this to take effect.

Comment: Thank you. For me also the GSSAPIAuthentication problem.

Comment: The problem arises with Centos 7 new instalation, but both configs resolve the problem, thanks.

Comment: Are there security implications to disabling `GSSAPIAuthentication` ? (googling for 15 minutes didn't shed light on that)

Comment: @AlexanderMalakhov If you're relying on this to log in, then you'll lock yourself out if you disable it. Other than that, no. And if you're using GSSAPI, you would know — you'd have had to configure some GSSAPI-based service on your network.

Comment: I tried GSSAPIAuthentication no in /etc/ssh/ssh_config on the client machine and it brought down ssh time from 24 seconds to 1. I did not change anything to ~/.ssh/config as there is no such file on my machine.

Comment: FWIW, there was no `UseDNS yes` in my config, so I assumed it was not on by default. (Note: defaults are normally still there in the config, but commented out, for doc. purposes.) Nevertheless, it still was on, and turning it off fixed the delay for me, too. Also note that `-vvv` doesn't really help in this case, as the debug dump itself also just gets stuck in the middle of a packet exchange, with no clear indication why. (It does suggest it's a server problem, but we already suspected that anyway.)

Comment: `UseDNS no` solved my problem, but it bugs me that not all my Ubuntu servers have this problem which is weird. Some digging into man page shows that some versions of openssh-server on Ubuntu have this option defaults to "yes" while other version have it defaults to "no", that's why only some servers have this problem.

Comment: I tested with "UseDNS no", then I checked the /etc/resolv.conf and noticed there were non-responding,, non reachable DNS IP addresses from a previous configuration. I removed them, then the authentication was normal again even with "UseDNS yes" setting.

Answer (score 16):

Let time the login process and see how long it will take:

```
[root@gislab00207 ~]# time ssh root@ISSLABNTL01
root@isslabntl01's password:
Last login: Fri Oct  4 07:55:03 2013 from 3.60.40.232

[root@ISSLABNTL01 ~]# exit
logout
Connection to ISSLABNTL01 closed.

real    0m45.192s
user    0m0.003s
sys     0m0.005s

You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/root
[root@gislab00207 ~]#
```

See above it took about 45 seconds to login -------- VERY SLOW

Once You login as root edit sshd_config file and change the UseDNS entry as below. 
Here I am using sed instead of editing the file.

```
[root@ISSLABNTL01 ~]# grep -i dns /etc/ssh/sshd_config
#UseDNS yes

[root@ISSLABNTL01 ~]# sed -i 's/#UseDNS yes/UseDNS no/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
[root@ISSLABNTL01 ~]# grep -i dns /etc/ssh/sshd_config
UseDNS no

[root@ISSLABNTL01 ~]# service sshd restart
Stopping sshd:                                             [  OK  ]
Starting sshd:                                             [  OK  ]
[root@ISSLABNTL01 ~]# exit
```

Let us time the login process and see now how long it will takes.

```
[root@gislab00207 ~]# time ssh root@ISSLABNTL01
root@isslabntl01's password:
Last login: Fri Oct  4 07:55:03 2013 from 3.60.40.232

[root@ISSLABNTL01 ~]# exit
logout

Connection to ISSLABNTL01 closed.

real    0m6.192s
user    0m0.003s
sys     0m0.005s

You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/root
[root@gislab00207 ~]#
```

See it took now 6 seconds, the time for me to type the password.

Comment: fantastic.. a point re time.. the useDNS no fixed it for me.. I had password authentication and the delay was for that password entering prompt to appear.. I waited for that to appear then did ctrl-c so the 'time' didn't include me entering the password.

Comment: I can confirm `UseDNS no` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` fixed my issue

Comment: `UseDNS no` Solved it

Comment: @PandurangPatil Bad configuration option: usedns

Comment: @zhilevan You should also mention why it is bad configuration. That will help understand why it's bad config

Comment: @PandurangPatil I'm on Mac and it seems this is a server config.

Answer (score 4):

It is something that comes wrong from Ubuntu's installation.

To fix it you have to change this line in **/etc/nsswitch.conf**:

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4
```

And change it for this one:

```
hosts:          files dns
```

Comment: Ubuntu's configuration isn't wrong. In some cases (home networks with no central DNS servers), it's the right thing. In others (networks where mDNS requests time out), it's bad.

Comment: the [NOTFOUND=return] should not be there.

Comment: @Neuquino It **should** be there. [It's there for a reason](http://www.unixguide.net/sun/faq/4.03.shtml) you don't understand, apparently. Fiddling with your `nsswitch.conf` like this is asking for trouble and not providing a general solution to slow SSH.

Comment: This seems to me the only solution that works

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the issue can be solved by restarting `systemd-logind`:

```
systemctl restart systemd-logind
```

This is mentioned [on Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/742102/30592).

I have to do this regularly though, and I don’t know what the root cause of the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

The debug output for ssh in my case just stopped for 30 seconds while it was 'connecting'. The solution turned out to be related to the DNS settings on my local system. A previous network configuration had left behind a bogus DNS server in the `/etc/resolv.conf` file. Replacing it with a current DNS server fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me was changing system dns to 127.0.0.1, prior to this is was a non-existing host.

```
nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

And write the following

```
domain localdomain
search localdomain
(Removed this line) ===> nameserver 10.0.0.1
(Added this line) ===> nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: For me, this file seemed to be /etc/resolv.conf (no e)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know as much about the poster's environment as I'd like to, but for others with a similar problem, it may be an issue with `sssd`, which we use to tie-in ldap mojo.

This happens to me:

```
$ time ssh server.example.com

real  2m0.018s
user  0m0.006s
sys   0m0.004s
```

I have to gain access to the server (in my case via the console) then do a:

```
service restart sssd
```

After that, things just work. I haven't had time to debug the root cause, but this bandaid works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the *slow password prompt via ssh* - issue by checking **Enable DNS Relay** in DHCP settings on my dlink router. Afterwards connections with SSH worked within a second.

```
Network Settings -> Router Settings -> Enable DNS Relay [x]
```

The default configuration forwards every DNS request to the provider. It was slow although I was connecting with ssh pi@10.0.0.103. A hint to the solution was an entry in /etc/resolv.conf "search upc.at" which is provided via dhcp.

The dlink manual states:

```
When DNS Relay is enabled, DHCP clients of the router will be assigned 
the router's LAN IP address as their DNS server. All DNS requests that 
the router receives will be forwarded to your ISPs DNS servers. 
When DNS relay is disabled, all DHCP clients of the router will 
be assigned the ISP's DNS server.
```

After a dhcp release on client and server, connecting via SSH was fast again. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, DNS was resolving over IPv6, for some reason it made `ssh` slower. I made an IPv4 entry in `/etc/hosts` on the client machine, and then `ssh`/`scp` was fast again.