# My Ubuntu on AWS is very slow

Tags: performance

I have Ubuntu 14.04.1 install on AWS and it was getting slower and slower
Not knowing what to do I updated and upgraded my system
It did not help

Testing disk usage (df -h) I get

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  5.9G  1.5G  80% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            492M   12K  492M   1% /dev
tmpfs           100M  356K   99M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            497M     0  497M   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
```

It takes me some 6-7 minutes to login using PuTTY (use to instant)
Where do I start?

Thanks

Comment: I think it's not generaly ubuntu problem. Thing you described looks like reverse dns problem. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/246323/why-does-sshs-password-prompt-take-so-long-to-appear

Comment: And please correct this, what becomes slower? Login, performance, disk activity?

Comment: Everything got slower: Login, web access, upload of files...
I looked at memory usage and it looks bad, here it is:
KiB Mem:   1016256 total,   948984 used,    67272 free,   110012 buffers
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 used,        0 free.   295940 cached Mem
I will now look at the revers DNS Problem as suggested
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Seeing that all resources are short (memory and disk) I upgraded my image to a new server with 4GB of ram and double the disk size and everything is back to normal.

**Nice and fast**

Thanks for all your help.